# gradle docker - how to skip build if build was done previously

Tags: gradle, docker-compose, dockerfile, build.gradle

I noticed the gradle:5.6.3-jdk8 always build the jar when I docker-compose up the yml file.

i thought the process will skip it if build completed earlier.

how to skip build if build was done previously?

**Docker compose file**

```html
  locationcommand:
    networks: 
      - abc
    build:
        context: ../../
        dockerfile: ./test-command/Dockerfile-test
    ports:
      - "8008:8008"
    hostname: testcommand
    container_name: testcommand
```

**Dockerfile-test**

```html
FROM gradle:5.6.3-jdk8 as builder

COPY . /home/gradle/src
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src
RUN gradle build
```

Comment: You are sure nothing is changed in `/home/gradle/src` between the runs?

Comment: nothing changed. just down and up docker compose